# Scala: implicit conversion not made?

Tags: scala, akka, implicits

```
[error] DeviceAffiliationCluster.scala:56: value ask is not a member of akka.actor.ActorRef
[error]   def ask(msg: Any): Future[Any] = deviceRegion.ask(msg)
[error]                                                 ^
[warn] DeviceAffiliationCluster.scala:5: Unused import
[warn] import akka.pattern.ask
```

`akka.pattern.ask` supplies an implicit conversion (from `ActorRef` to `AskableActorRef`, the latter which provides the method `ask`)

When I compile using sbt, however, the conversion is NOT recognized. (Intellij sees the implicit conversion and has no issue with it, but I'm using sbt to build.)

I can get it to work explicitly:

```
val deviceRegion: ActorRef =  ...

val deviceRegionAskable: AskableActorRef = deviceRegion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that your method `ask` is hiding the ask method which you imported from `akka.pattern.ask` If you use a different method name then your example works fine

```
  import akka.actor._
  import akka.pattern.ask
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import scala.concurrent._

  class FooActor extends Actor {
    def receive = {
    case s: String => sender ! s"Hello $s"
    }}
  val ac = ActorSystem()
  implicit val ec : ExecutionContext = ac.dispatcher
  val fooAc = ac.actorOf(Props[FooActor], "fa")
  implicit val to = new akka.util.Timeout(10 seconds)
  def ask2(msg: Any) : Future[Any] = fooAc.ask("foo")
  val x = Await.result(ask2("foo"), Duration.Inf)
  println(x)
```

Comment: Oh, sheesh! Thank you.

Comment: But, wait, I was looking for an ask on deviceRegion, a member val, not on this.

Comment: ask is an implicit method which will not be provided to you, if there was already an ask in the context. if there is no ask then the implicit mechanism looks for the ask and finds it in the import of akka.patten.ask.